# python pygame py2app application does not open

Tags: macos, pygame, py2app

I am using py2app to convert a simple python pygame file into an app

I have two files, the setup file and a python window file
and I enter "python /path py2app" and get no errors, but when
I open window.app I get the error box below:

[image: Error window]

When I click on "Open Console" I see that the error that occurred was:

> Console Error: ([0x0-0x178178].org.pythonmac.unspecified.window[2347])
>   Exited with code: 255

When I type python window.app in terminal I ge the error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't find '__main__' module in '/Users/williamfiset/dist/window.app'
```

**window.py:**

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *
import pygame._view

black    = (   0,   0,   0)
pygame.init()
size=[700,500]
screen=pygame.display.set_mode(size)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            isRunning = False
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    screen.fill(black)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(20)
```

**setup.py:**

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['window.py']
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True, 'includes': ['EXTERNAL LIBRARY'],}

setup(
      app=APP,
      options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
      setup_requires=['py2app'],
      )
```

When I replace the window.py file with the following I do not get any errors. The window opens 
fine without errors.

```
import Tkinter

t = Tkinter.Tk()
t.geometry("700x500+300+100")
t.mainloop()
```

Comment: I solved the problem myself by removing "**import pygame._view**" in window.py.